# Link to a folder in the top Ubuntu panel

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I like the little top panel thing in Ubuntu. I have links to all my most used programs on there. (Which is why I don't see the point of docky or any of those things: they seem to do the same job, but they're messier).

What I'd like is to have a little icon for my documents folder up there too. But I don't seem to be able to do it. It's not one of the options listed when you go to "add to panel...". Am I missing something ridiculously easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Custom application launcher, and then there's a drop down box that you can change from `application` to `location`.

Now I just need to change the icon and I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'places' menu you should be able to right click and view the properties of the bookmarks. If you look in the command property you should be able to see how this works and copy it to a new shortcut to add to the panel.

Comment: Right clicking on something in the "Places" menu just opens that folder. And I don't want to add something to the places menu, I want a shortcut that has its own icon on the panel I can just click on immediately.

Comment: what I was trying to say is look at how places work as I am sure they are as you say application launchers with location instead of application or a command.

Answer (score 0):

Just open nautilus and drag and drop the desire folder to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Nautilus is the way to go. I tried dragging it from inside the 'Places' Menu. Add something to the Panel = find launcher in Nautilus

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your answer.